# Counting number of words and lines in a file in Python

Tags: python

How to write a function that reads a file and appends line number and the number of words in the line at the end of each line?

The expected output should be something like the following

```
Hello world, how are you? 1 5 # first line, 5 words
I am good. 2 3 #second line 3 words
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's the issue with your current code?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this will make essay writing much easier.

Comment: Check out how to ask questions.https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible in python to have a def w() tha could open a file with a word count for every line and a line counter while still having the original text from the file?

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a more concise answer than @ironkey however if you are new to python you might find theirs clearer.

```
with open('data.text', 'r') as f:
  for line_cnt, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
    word_cnt = len(line.split(" "))
    print(line, f"| {line_cnt} | {word_cnt}")
```

Edit: Used enumerate as suggested to make it even shorter.

Comment: instead of maintaining that `line_cnt` you should use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate): `for line_cnt, line in enumerate(f, 1)`